# How do I get all values of checkbox those are checked using ajax/jQuery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

When i click the Select working days / hours Checkbox the list of days will be displayed. for example if i click the sunday checkbox check box the value entered in the checkbox should be call to javascript function. in case am not click the checkbox the value display should be Null.

[**DEMO LINK HTML**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/9z6ttkvo/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("input#btnDocBusinesshours").click(function () { SaveDocBusinesshours(null) });
        });
```

Call Ajax Function

```
function callAjax(jparms) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: jparms.url,
                data: jparms.data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (jparms.action == "SaveDocBusinesshours")
                        SaveDocBusinesshours(response.d)

                },
                failure: function (response) { response.d; }
            });
        }
```

Save Ajax Function

```
 function SaveDocBusinesshours(response) {
            var values = $('input[type="checkbox"].single:checked').map(function () {
                return $(this).val();
            }).toArray();


            if (response == null) {
                callAjax({
                    url: pageUrl + '/SaveDocBusinesshours',
                    data: '{"Doctorid": "' + $("#<%=hdnDoctorId.ClientID %>").val() + '","WorkingDaysID" : "' + $("#<%=hdnBusiness.ClientID %>").val() + '","Sunday" : "' + $("#<%=ChkSUN.ClientID %>").val() + '","Monday" : "' + $("#<%=ChkMON.ClientID %>").val() + '","Thuesday" : "' + $("#<%=ChkTUE.ClientID %>").val() + '"}',
                    action: "SaveDocBusinesshours"
                });
                window.location.reload();
            }
            else {
                loading(false);
                if (response.AjxContactId != null) {
                    $('#<%=hdnBusiness.ClientID%>').val(response.AjxContactId);
                }
                msg(true, response.Message);
            }

        }
```

Webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static UserAjax SaveDocBusinesshours(string Doctorid, string WorkingDaysID, string Sunday, string Monday, string Thuesday)
    {
        UserAjax oUserAjax = new UserAjax();
        return oUserAjax;
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand what your problem is? is it not receiving the correct data in the back end? Also your js fiddle does not have the SaveDocBusinesshours method

Comment: The first line of your SaveDocBusinesshours get the selected checkboxes values

Comment: am new for this technology so please help me ..what to do?@LiverpoolOwen

Comment: I need to know your issue in order to help you

Comment: When i click the  Checkbox button the value get and call to ajax function ..but in my code is not working checkbox @LiverpoolOwen

Comment: The javascript you have posted is set up on the button click not the checkbox click

Comment: yes i got it now .. how to obtain check box value while i onclick the function @LiverpoolOwen

Comment: So you want to hit the method on the check box click instead of the button?

Comment: okay thanks @LiverpoolOwen